# Identify this 'Cinderella' font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-design

Can anyone help me identify the font used for 'Cinderella'. I can't seem to place it. Thanks! [image]

Comment: There are many font identifier websites, where you can upload the image and it will give you set of matching fonts as a result; that too free of cost.
Some provide you an option to even download that font for free or if its a paid font it will link you to that website. You can visit this link: [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont) .
It's one of the popular online tool to identify fonts. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Finding an exact match to a script font is difficult. WhatTheFont (suggested in a comment above) shows Flemish Script II by Monotype and Lockhart by Danie Type among the choices. These come close, but are not quite right, especially the capital C.

Another tool to try: WhatFontIs.com.

To help any of these tools, remove the black drop shadow and the top line of text. It also helps to darken the yellow to create more contrast.